# Ejb action event update

Tags: jsf, ejb

I have two pages, one page has a command button (page 1)with a backed action event that update the database. The other page has a data table that display the value of that database.(page 2)

When I trigger that command on page 1 and navigate to page two the data table is not updating. I am using primeface (jsf) and ejb.

So I was wondering if `Requestcontext.update(":page2:datatable")` will update the data table on page two or is there a better way of updating the datatable.

Comment: Make sure your managed beans have a small scope like `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped`. Also, check that the data is updated in your database and you recover the list in page 2 from database and not from a session parameter.

Comment: 1)"page 2" is not a DOM element id so you cant address it the way you're attempting. 2)`RequestContext` is only valid for the current request, navigating to another page breaks the current request. 3)If a full page render,triggered by navigation, doesn't update your datatable, an ajax call won't  update it. Your code has a fundamental problem that all the ajax tricks in the known universe will not overcome. Please post your code here if you need any assistance with it

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am using a '@SessionScoped' is that ok

Comment: @user1817081 the problem will be that the bean will be stored in session, so when you revisit the page it won't create the bean which means that the list won't update it's values from calling to the database (at least that's how it must be if you follow JSF good practices as not having business logic in your getter/setter methods).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a good place to read over JSF good practice?